# Capture/Transfer mini DV camcorder using DVGrab

Tags: firewire

Problem Statement: I can't get PC to see the camera and capture video file. I've been using dvgrab which reports no camera exists.

I've reviewed responses on many forums and installed a few different distro's. I tried to install an older version of Ubuntu to see if that would work but after a few hours trying couldn't manage to do that. I was able to capture videos on an old win 7 PC but it has died unfortunately.

I would really really appreciate some help so I can put these treasured memories on a media server for the family.

Setup: HP Probook 6470b, Panasonic NV-MX1 camcorder, connected with firewire. Latest Ubuntu installed (see report at bottom)

My research seems to indicate that the legacy firewire stack was replaced by a newer version which no longer created \dev\raw1394 and instead creates \dev\fw0I've tried using the ln command to link these and chmod to change permissions. dvgrab still reporting no camera exists.

As a desperate measure I tried to install an legacy ubuntu version pre firewire change but I couldn't get that to work. I tried to find a way to install the older firewire stack but couldn't.

I am open to hardware and software options with the proviso it keeps the video digital and quality the same.

## System Details Report

---

### Report details

- **Date generated:**                              2024-03-10 23:20:41

### Hardware Information:

- **Hardware Model:**                              Hewlett-Packard HP ProBook 6470b
- **Memory:**                                      4.0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i5-3230M × 4
- **Graphics:**                                    Intel® HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)
- **Disk Capacity:**                               500.1 GB

### Software Information:

- **Firmware Version:**                            68ICE Ver. F.45
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 23.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               45.2
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.5.0-25-generic

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding yourself to the `video` group: Do: `sudo adduser $USER video`, then logout and login.

Comment: Fixed it - new cable! Original cable had worked previously but it wasn't a good fit indicating it was low quality. Delighted and learned a load about Linux on the way